# Multiple generic type for a class java

Tags: java, generics, collections, singleton

is there a way to use a class, with generic types, without setting the maximum number?
I have this class

```
public class Repository<V> {
    private Map<String, HashSet<V>> repo = new HashMap<>();
    private static Repository instance = null;

    private Repository() {}
    
    public static synchronized Repository getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new Repository();
        }
        
        return instance;
    }
    
    public void addRepository(String key) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        repo.put(key, new HashSet<>());
    }

    .....
}
```

this is a "general repository", the `HashMap` contains an identifier as a key while as a value have `HashSet<V>` with the data.

I would like each `HashSet` in the `HashMap` to contain different class types. More precisely, I would like the generic type `V` to be different for each `HashSet` within the `HashMap`

how can i fix the code to be able to achieve this result?

Comment: No.  You'd have to pass in a Type variable for each time you want and that would get insanely messy.  The better solution is create a repository for each type.

Comment: You can use `HashSet<?>` to represent a hash set of unknown type. But it won't be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a class parameter such as `Repository<V>` and expect `V` to be different for each type of entry in the map.

However, you may do something like this:

Remove the generic type from Repository:

```
public class Repository {
}
```

Generify the repository map so that it takes a `Class<?>` as key (instead of a String) and a `Set<?>` as value):

```
private final Map<Class<?>, Set<?>> repo = new HashMap<>();
```

Then, create one method to add a new repository and a method to get an existing repository as such:

```
public <T> void addRepository(Class<T> key) {
    Set<?> existing = repo.putIfAbsent(key, new HashSet<>());
    if (existing != null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key " + key + " is already associated to a repository");
    }
}

public <T> Set<T> getRepository(Class<T> key) {
    Set<?> subRepo = repo.get(key);
    if (subRepo == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No repository found for key " + key);
    }
    return (Set<T>) subRepo; //unchecked cast
}
```

Note: the `getRepository()` will perform an unchecked cast, but it is a "safe" unchecked cast since the only way to add a new entry into your map is passing through `<T> void addRepository(Class<T> key)` and you won't be able to insert values that are not `T` inside the returned `Set<T>`.

Sample usage:

```
Repository repository = Repository.getInstance();
repository.addRepository(String.class);
repository.addRepository(Integer.class);
Set<String> stringRepo = repository.getRepository(String.class);
stringRepo.add("Hey");
stringRepo.add("Jude");
Set<Integer> intRepo = repository.getRepository(Integer.class);
intRepo.add(1);
intRepo.add(4);
```

However, I think you should have one repository per type, it would be cleaner because with the above solution, you're basically not leveraging at all on Java generics (except for the method `<T>` used in the `getRepository` method, for which you need to perform an unchecked cast anyway).

Comment: Provided implementation of `addRepository()` is fine, it's well readable, but JIC it can be written in a single statement: `repo.merge(key, new HashSet<>(), (oldVal, newVal) -> { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key " + key + " is already associated to a repository"); };`.

Comment: Thank you so much for a reply. My problem is that I would like to keep the Singleton pattern valid, i.e. I don't want multiple instances to be created for the single type but one per type. so i wanted to try this solution

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to achieve that cleanly. You can create a repository for each type you have, but you can not unite them into one repository with this setup.

Comment: how could I do to create a repository for each type always respecting the singleton? (ie I can only have one instance of each type) all this without creating a specialized class for each type.